# SQL query group by metadata value field

Tags: sql, metadata

I have a webshop which works with WOOCOMMERCE and I need some statistics.

I build the SQL Query which you can find as Code.

I would need a "group by function for the pm.meta.value field "buchungsbezeichnung".

I get a row for each p.posts entry at the moment. That are a lot of columns and I must use excel-pivot to get the right statistic.

I would need only the sum at the column "Bankzahlung" or column "Mitgliedszahlung" for each meta value "buchungsbezeichnung".

I tried a lot but I can't find the right SQL query.

Please help me.
Thanks
Regards Siegfried

```
  p.ID AS 'Order ID',
  CASE p.post_status
      WHEN 'wc-pending'    THEN 'Zahlung Ausstehend'
      WHEN 'wc-processing' THEN 'in Bearbeitung'
      WHEN 'wc-on-hold'    THEN 'Wartestellung'
      WHEN 'wc-completed'  THEN 'Best. ausgeliefert'
      WHEN 'wc-cancelled'  THEN 'Storniert'
      WHEN 'wc-refunded'   THEN 'Rückerstattet'
      WHEN 'wc-failed'     THEN 'Fehlgeschlagen'
      WHEN 'wc-ausgeliefert' THEN 'Ausgeliefert'
      WHEN 'wc-pfand' THEN 'Pfand'
      WHEN 'wc-bestellung-neu' THEN 'Bestellung Neu'
      WHEN 'wc-produzent-vorbest' THEN 'Bei Produzent vorbestellt'
      WHEN 'wc-produzent-best' THEN 'Bestellung b. Produzent'
      WHEN 'wc-ladenausgabe' THEN 'Ladenausgabe'
      WHEN 'wc-bewirtungsbeitrag' THEN 'Bewirtungsbeitrag'
      WHEN 'wc-enw-bank-gh-mi' THEN '11 W_Buchg. Bankueberw. GH'
      WHEN 'wc-enw-umbu-gh-vj' THEN '12 W_Buchg. Übertrag GH VJ'
      WHEN 'wc-enw-barz-gh-mi' THEN '13 W_Buchg. Barzahlung'
      WHEN 'wc-enw-nachl-vj' THEN '14 W_Buchg. Nachlass VJ'
      WHEN 'wc-env-bank-mb-mi' THEN '21 V_Buchg. Bankueberw. MB'
      WHEN 'wc-env-umbu-mb-vj' THEN '22 V_Buchg. Übertrag MB VJ'
      WHEN 'wc-env-bank-gh-so' THEN '23 V_Buchg. Verein Sonstiges'
      WHEN 'wc-agw-zahlung-prod' THEN '31 W_Buchg. Zahlg. RE Prod'
      WHEN 'wc-agw-umb-re-prod' THEN '31 W_Umbu. Zahlg. RE Prod Mitgl'
      WHEN 'wc-agv-austr-mitgl' THEN '32 W-Buchg. Zahlg. RZ Austritt'
      WHEN 'wc-agv-it' THEN '41 V-Buchg. Zahlg. RE IT'
      WHEN 'wc-agv-shop' THEN '42 V-Buchg. Zahlg. RE Shop'
      WHEN 'wc-agv-trans' THEN '43 V-Buchg. Zahlg. RE Trans'
      WHEN 'wc-agv-verw' THEN '44 V-Buchg. Zahlg. RE Verw' 
      WHEN 'wc-xxx-umbu-gh-mb' THEN '51 Umb. Guthaben zu MB'
      WHEN 'wc-ugw-u-zahlung-pro' THEN '52 Umb. Zahlg RE Prod d. Mitgl.'
      WHEN 'wc-gutschrift-mitgli' THEN '53 Gutschrift Mitgl.'
      WHEN 'wc-ugv-ausumb-it' THEN '61 Umb. Zahlg RE IT d. Mitgl.'
      WHEN 'wc-ugv-ausumb-shop' THEN '62 Umb. Zahlg RE Shop d. Mitgl.'
      WHEN 'wc-ugv-ausumb-trans' THEN '63 Umb. Zahlg RE Trans d. Mitgl.' 
      WHEN 'wc-ugv-ausumb-verw' THEN '64 Umb. Zahlg RE Verw d. Mitgl.' 
      WHEN 'wc-mitgliedsbeitrag' THEN '71 Ford. Mitgliedsbeitrag'
      WHEN 'wc-ford-mb-mahn' THEN '72 Ford-Mahn. Mitgliedsbeitrag'
    ELSE 'kein Status'
    END AS 'Status',
       
  MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'monatsverrechnung' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Monatsverrechnung',
  MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzgruppe' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Bilanzgruppe',
  MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'buchungsbezeichnung' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Buchungsbez',
  MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzwert' AND p.ID = pm.post_id AND p.post_status = 'wc-ugw-u-zahlung-pro' THEN (0-pm.meta_value) END ) AS 'Bankzahlung',
  MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzwert' AND p.ID = pm.post_id AND p.post_status = 'wc-agw-zahlung-prod' THEN (pm.meta_value) END ) AS 'Mitgliedszahlung'
 
FROM  KtS4szE8u_posts AS p 
JOIN  KtS4szE8u_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id

group by p.id

WHERE
    p.post_status  IN('wc-agw-zahlung-prod','wc-ugw-u-zahlung-pro')
```

Comment: You could use your current query as a sub query and select from it. You need to filter only posts where pm.meta is `'buchungsbezeichnung'`. For example `SELECT SUM("Bankzahlung"), SUM("Mitgliedszahlung") FROM [current query AND pm.meta_key = 'buchungsbezeichnung'] AS subquery`

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

First, it might better you both now and in the future to have a lookup table of your different statuses of wc-pending, wc-processing, wc-on-hold, etc with a corresponding heading.  Something like below and would have been a LOT EASIER done up front than trying to back-fill the database by using the ID key for status/headings

```
Table PostStatus (lookup table with index on postStatus column)
PostStatusID  Post_Status           Post_Heading
1             wc-pending           Zahlung Ausstehend
2             wc-processing        in Bearbeitung
3             wc-on-hold           Wartestellung
4             wc-completed         Best. ausgeliefert
5             wc-cancelled         Storniert
etc... for all other entries.
xx            wc-mitgliedsbeitrag  71 Ford. Mitgliedsbeitrag
```

Then, you could join and simplify your case to

```
select
      p.ID 'Order ID',
      coalesce( ps.post_heading, 'kein Status' ) Status,
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'monatsverrechnung' 
               THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Monatsverrechnung',
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzgruppe' 
               THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Bilanzgruppe',
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'buchungsbezeichnung' 
                THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Buchungsbez',
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzwert' 
                    AND p.post_status = 'wc-ugw-u-zahlung-pro' 
                THEN (0-pm.meta_value) END ) AS 'Bankzahlung',
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzwert' 
                    AND p.post_status = 'wc-agw-zahlung-prod' 
                THEN (pm.meta_value) END ) AS 'Mitgliedszahlung'
    from 
      KtS4szE8u_posts AS p 
         -- using the LEFT-JOIN so you can get status readable values
         LEFT JOIN PostStatus ps 
            on p.post_status = ps.post_status
         -- now join for your meta data too
         JOIN  KtS4szE8u_postmeta pm 
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
   group by 
      p.id
   WHERE
      p.post_status IN ('wc-agw-zahlung-prod', 'wc-ugw-u-zahlung-pro' )
```

Since your WHERE clause is only pulling out 2 possible status codes, the rest of your CASE statement would only need those 2 possible values anyhow and the rest would never even be in the output.  By using the lookup table, you still get whatever readable heading you wanted with just the 2, or 100 if you had a 100 different status codes.

As for your MAX( case/when ) conditions, you dont need to explicitly add the  AND `p.id = pm.post_id` because that is already part of the JOIN condition.

Now, back to your original question.  You need a count of something.  It SOUNDS like you need to wrap what you have above based into an outer query but you will need to tweak it.  But, if you DONT have a lookup table, and you are only dealing with TWO possible post-status values to begin with, that too could be simplified as I'll include below, but you should consider the lookup table for actual.

```
select
      p.ID 'Order ID',
      -- again, simplified CASE/WHEN since your where clause is only ever
      -- returning records for these two status conditions
      case when p.post_status = 'wc-agw-zahlung-prod'
           then '31 W_Buchg. Zahlg. RE Prod'
           else '52 Umb. Zahlg RE Prod d. Mitgl.' end Status
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'monatsverrechnung' 
               THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Monatsverrechnung',
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzgruppe' 
               THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Bilanzgruppe',
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'buchungsbezeichnung' 
                THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS 'Buchungsbez',
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzwert' 
                    AND p.post_status = 'wc-ugw-u-zahlung-pro' 
                THEN (0-pm.meta_value) END ) AS 'Bankzahlung',
      MAX( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'bilanzwert' 
                    AND p.post_status = 'wc-agw-zahlung-prod' 
                THEN (pm.meta_value) END ) AS 'Mitgliedszahlung'
    from 
      KtS4szE8u_posts AS p 
         JOIN  KtS4szE8u_postmeta pm 
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
   group by 
      p.id
   WHERE
      p.post_status IN ('wc-agw-zahlung-prod', 'wc-ugw-u-zahlung-pro' )
```

Now, to wrap, use EITHER method I posted above

```
select
      sum( case when PreSumResult.Status = '31 W_Buchg. Zahlg. RE Prod'
           then 1 else 0 end ) as CountOf31Posts,
      sum( case when PreSumResult.Status = '31 W_Buchg. Zahlg. RE Prod'
           then Mitgliedszahlung else 0 end ) as SumOfMitgliedszahlung,
      sum( case when PreSumResult.Status = '52 Umb. Zahlg RE Prod d. Mitgl.'
           then 1 else 0 end ) as CountOf52Posts,
      sum( case when PreSumResult.Status = '52 Umb. Zahlg RE Prod d. Mitgl.'
           then Bankzahlung else 0 end ) as SumOfBankzahlung 
   from
      ( either of the above queries ) as PreSumResult
```

So the pre-query already does the aggregation/separation qualifier for you with the meta data.  Then that becomes the alias "PreSumResult" for the outer query getting the respective counts and sum values respectively.